# Codeigniter Integrate FB login with Web login

Tags: codeigniter, controller, facebook-login

I have a web sign up system and I want to add a facebook sign up feature and possible a google+. What is the best approach to integrate the systems without overlapping data?

The thing is that the web sign up is triggered when a button is pressed and the facebook sign up is triggered when an anchor  type button is pressed. Can I make a controller for when the anchor is pressed and build the href link inside?

HTML

```
<!-- Button for Web Log in -->    
<input type="submit" name="regisSubmit" id="regisSubmit" tabindex="5" 
class="form-control btn btn-register" value="Register now">

<!-- <a> for Fb Log in -->  
<?php  echo '<a href="'.$authUrl.'"><img 
src="'.base_url().'assets/images/flogin.png" alt=""/></a>'; ?>
```

Comment: *"The thing is..."* Show the thing. Edit your question and post all relevant code. [This article](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) can help you in decision what to post to look good to others. Also, [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: For Facebook SDK V5 integration in CodeIgniter refer https://shareurcodes.com/blog/facebook%20php%20sdk%20v5%20with%20codeigniter and for Google authentication in codeigniter 3 refer https://shareurcodes.com/blog/login%20with%20google%20codeigniter